# Trigger button click from other button

Tags: javascript, jquery, squarespace

I'm trying to trigger a button click from another button to use in my squarespace website.

I'm adding the following to the header:

```js
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        offerteHeader = $( "a.theme-btn--primary-inverse:contains('Offerte aanvragen')" );
        offerteForm = $("button:contains('Offerte aanvragen')");
        offerteHeader.removeAttr("href");
        offerteHeader.on( "click", function() {offerteForm.click()});
    });
</script>
```

When I click the OfferteHeader button nothing happens :(.

OfferteHeader and offerteForm seem to refference fine when I log the to the console.

Also firing offerteForm.click() from the chrome dev console seem to work fine and trigger the event.

I also checked if the listener was working with a log to the console and if it could refference to offerteForm.

What is the problem here? The site can be found on https://sturgeon-groundhog-cnzt.squarespace.com/ password is bellboy. Sorry, it's a squarespace site, can not change that.

Comment: `console.log(offerteForm.length)`

Comment: @Taplar that returns 1

Comment: Try `offerteForm.submit()`

Comment: @TamasSzoke that does not work

Comment: @Taplar when I set a breakpoint in chrome dev tools at line 7. Then it does work.

Comment: Could you add a runnable [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) that fully reproduces the problem?

Comment: @TamasSzoke you can try it here: https://sturgeon-groundhog-cnzt.squarespace.com/ password is bellboy. See if offerteForm.click() works in the console for you? 

See line 43 in index for the snippet.

Comment: Trigger the click event already bound to `offerteForm`, e.g: `offerteForm.trigger('click');` (https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: Ok, just to rule this out.  Would you try changing `removeAttr('href')` to `attr('href', '#')` and see if anything behaves differently?

Comment: @Taplar That doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Alright, well, I was wondering if the removal of the href was causing the link to not register a click event, but that rules that out.

Comment: @Taplar I also read something like that, but I think it's only for new href attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this isn't best practice but working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var offerteHeader = $("a.theme-btn--primary-inverse:contains('Offerte aanvragen')");
  var offerteForm = $("button:contains('Offerte aanvragen')");
  offerteHeader.click(function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      offerteForm.trigger("click")
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var offerteHeader = $("a.theme-btn--primary-inverse:contains('Offerte aanvragen')");
  var offerteForm = $("button:contains('Offerte aanvragen')");
  offerteHeader.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    offerteForm.trigger("click");
  });
});
```

See more: https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix it. Trigger("click") does not work in the chrome dev console. So I tried replacing it with offerteForm.click() which also did not work. This does work in the chrome dev console.

Comment: @RémonvanNieuwenhuizen not exactly the best way to test new code. Should test in JSFiddle or in raw HTML File.

Comment: I have no other way since I'm locked down to integrate with the squarespace template. A requirement made because of company reasons.